# ArcGIS Javascript API - How to add multiple states to existing map?

Tags: dojo, arcgis, esri, arcgis-js-api, esri-arc-engine

I am new to ARCGIS. Can someone show me how can I go about adding 2 states New Jersey and Delaware to the existing code? So that it displays along with  New York.

Is there  also a wild card option to add all the states?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <!--The viewport meta tag is used to improve the presentation and behavior of the samples 
      on iOS devices-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
    <title>Class Breaks Renderer</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/esri/css/esri.css">
    <style>
      html, body, #map{
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
    </style>
    <script src="http://js.arcgis.com/3.11/"></script>
    <script>

    //https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jssamples/renderer_class_breaks.html
      var map;
      require([
        "esri/map", "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
        "esri/InfoTemplate", "esri/symbols/SimpleFillSymbol", 
        "esri/renderers/ClassBreaksRenderer",
        "esri/Color", "dojo/dom-style", "dojo/domReady!"
      ], function(
        Map, FeatureLayer,
        InfoTemplate, SimpleFillSymbol, 
        ClassBreaksRenderer,
        Color, domStyle
      ) {
        map = new Map("map", {
          basemap: "streets",
          center: [-74.215, 42.382],
          zoom: 7,
          slider: false
        });

        var symbol = new SimpleFillSymbol();
        symbol.setColor(new Color([150, 150, 150, 0.5]));

        // Add five breaks to the renderer.
        // If you have ESRI's ArcMap available, this can be a good way to determine break values.
        // You can also copy the RGB values from the color schemes ArcMap applies, or use colors
        // from a site like www.colorbrewer.org
        //
        // alternatively, ArcGIS Server's generate renderer task could be used
        var renderer = new ClassBreaksRenderer(symbol, "POP07_SQMI");
        renderer.addBreak(0, 25, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([56, 168, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(25, 75, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([139, 209, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(75, 175, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255, 255, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(175, 400, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255, 128, 0, 0.5])));
        renderer.addBreak(400, Infinity, new SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new Color([255, 0, 0, 0.5])));

        var infoTemplate = new InfoTemplate("${NAME}", "${*}");
        var featureLayer = new FeatureLayer("http://sampleserver1.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/Demographics/ESRI_Census_USA/MapServer/3", {
          mode: FeatureLayer.MODE_SNAPSHOT,
          outFields: ["*"],
          infoTemplate: infoTemplate
        });

        featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME = 'New York'");
        featureLayer.setRenderer(renderer);
        map.addLayer(featureLayer);
      });
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to alter the definition expression in your example to include the other states so you can say

```
featureLayer.setDefinitionExpression("STATE_NAME IN ('New York', 'New Jersey', 'Delaware')");
```

if you remove that line it will add all the states.

You can see a working example at http://jsfiddle.net/q1tvcpak/